# Is there a way to plot matplotlib graphs (.history) for tensorflow models from a loaded model checkpoint?

Tags: python, docker, tensorflow, matplotlib, conv-neural-network

I have trained a few CNN models in tensorflow, however i forgot to use the 'history' function to plot a graph afterwards for both accuracy and loss.

I have both the weights and the entire model saved, but didn't realise you need to plot .history graphs in the same execution cycle as the training epochs.

Is there a way to generate accuracy and loss graphs post-training the model from a saved checkpoint or from a model save?

Answer (score 0):

The weights or `tensorflow.train.checkpoint` doesn't save metric or loss history because it is waste of memory.
However, if the `model.fit(*)` was the last function you executed, you can try with `_` or `__` depends on your IDE that saves the last outputs. (https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/role-underscore-python)